# Remove cascade onDelete constraint from table using sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, cascade

I have a locations and devices table . Devices table have location id and this is how the model looks like

```
 module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const devices = sequelize.define('devices', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    location_id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: true,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      references: {
        model: 'locations',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    model: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  
    created_at: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    updated_at: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
  }, {});
  devices.associate = function (models) {
    devices.belongsTo(models.companies, { foreignKey: 'company_id' });
    devices.belongsTo(models.locations, { as: 'locations', foreignKey: 'location_id' });
  };
  return devices;
};
```

Migration looks like below

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('devices', {
    id: {
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        location_id: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          allowNull: true,
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          references: {
            model: 'locations',
            key: 'id',
          },
        },
        model: {
          allowNull: true,
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
      
        created_at: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.DATE,
        },
        updated_at: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.DATE,
        },
  }),
  down: (queryInterface) => queryInterface.dropTable('devices'),
};
```

The above causes device to be deleted along with location .

This is already migrated.

Now I have a requirement to remove onDelete cascade so that delete of location won't result in device getting deleted .

How to write a migration to drop onDelete cascade?

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
        await queryInterface.changeColumn('devices', 'location_id', {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: true,
            // onDelete: 'CASCADE',  <-    Remove this line
            references: {
                model: 'locations',
                key: 'id',
            },
        });
    },

    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    }
};
```